# Connect our Google App Engine Python API to an external MySQL database on Digital Ocean

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There are already many questions about how to connect to an external MySQL database but they all focus on how to open a remote connection, which is simply fixed by enabling billing.

However none if these questions address how to open an exception in your MySQL database so that the GCP App engine can connect to it. Normally a static IP would do, except it seems static IPs are for Compute Instances VM.

It seems like the previous solution was using "Google Secure Data Connector", but it's been decommissioned.

I found something else on [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-third-party-databases) that says:

> Your App Engine app connects over the Internet using that external
>   service's public IP address.

However there is no further information and I have no idea if that address is static or ephemeral, but [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) seems to say the address will never be static and can not be assigned a static IP:

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses
>   to an application.

Has anyone ever succeeded? How did you set your exception on the external, non-GCP MySQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppEngine can connect to internet but with a pool of IP address. You can't define one and use always the same. If your Database has to authorize only one IP it's not yet supported.

However, you could cheat by plugging a serverless VPC Connector to your AppEngine and using a VM as proxy but the solution is ugly and I don't guaranty good response time, which is critical for a database...